# get random item from listBox c#

Tags: c#

i have a listBox and i want everytime show random item from my list.

```
var random = new Random();

 int index = random.Next(listBox1.Items.Count);
 Console.Writeline(listBox1.Items[index].toString());
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What did you try already, what exception are you getting? Provide details. Share your research.

Comment: So what happens with this code?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var random = new Random();

 int index = random.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);
 Console.Writeline(listBox1.Items[index].toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var random=new Random();
int index=random.Next(0,listBox1.Items.Count);
```

Basically random.Next(min,max) require min and max values so that random number is generated between the  given range.
You should provide range also .

```
Console.Writeline(listBox1.Items[index].toString());
```

Comment: If this code would be in a loop, OP would get the same result always. You need to create one instance of random and lock it on object to generate different values.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky It's not true. Every instance of `Random` class has new seed based on current time. But is good practice to share single instance of `Random` class.

Comment: There are different overloads of `Random.Next()`. If you invoke `Next(int i)`, so with one `int` parameter it is set as the max value and the min value is default 0. It doesnt change anything if the min value is default set to 0 or if you set it to 0.
 So there is no difference between `int index = random.Next(listBox1.Items.Count);`  and `int index = random.Next(0, listBox1.Items.Count);`.

Comment: Every time you do new Random() it is initialized using the clock. This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You should keep a single Random instance and keep using Next on the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

I just use your code @ilyas it's working fine, stick with it, just use

```
MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[index].ToString());
```

instead of

```
Console.Writeline(listBox1.Items[index].toString());
```

i assume you are creating WinForm Application

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok. But if you are using it in a tight loop, it would give you always the same number. Maybe this is your problem?

> Every time you do `new Random()` it is initialized using the clock.

This means that in a tight loop you get the same value lots of times. You should keep a single Random instance and keep using **Next** on the same instance.

```
//Define your random class with a static field
public static class RandomAccessor {
    // Static field for your Random to create one instance only
    private static readonly Random random = new Random(); 
    // Object to lock sync on
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object(); 
    // Method to generate random number
    public static int RandomNumber(int max)
    {
        lock(syncLock) {
            // returns a random non-negative number less that max
            return random.Next(max); 
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in your code like this:

```
int index = RandomAccessor.RandomNumber(listBox1.Items.Count);
Console.Writeline(listBox1.Items[index].toString());
```

Ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example how it will work.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SimpleFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly Random _random = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_random_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int randomIndex = _random.Next(listBox1.Items.Count);
            var randomItem = listBox1.Items[randomIndex];
            MessageBox.Show($"Random item at index {randomIndex} is {randomItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

Please also have a look in here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.100).aspx and exermine the examples there.